# Previously accepted answer got deleted and unaccepted later: lost the 15 rep acceptance bonus twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, deleted-answers, unaccepted-answer

I answered a [question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/what-causes-gender-differences-in-responses-to-farting) on [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) on July, 3rd, which got accepted quite quickly and got 2 up-votes right away (i.e., +35 rep). However, my answer was not correct and it got 5 down-votes afterwards (-10 rep).

On July, 4th, it got (rightfully!) deleted because people noticed that it wasn't meant seriously and I lost all the rep associated to this answer (-25).
Today the OP marked another answer as correct, causing my answer getting unaccepted which lost me another 15 rep.

A quick calculation reveals that, in total, from the gained 25 rep, I lost 40.

Although this punishment by -15 rep might be appropriate given the lack of respect I showed, **I still would like to know whether is this also intended by the system**.

Reputation history associated to the deleted answer:

[image: screenhsot]

Deleted answer including the display of all up- and down-votes:

[image]

Comment: I smell a bug; retagged as such. You should not loose the 15 points twice.

Comment: I have recalculated your rep, so it's correct once more. We'll look at how this happened.

Comment: @balpha: Many thanks. Had I known before that rep gets replaced so quickly here, I had written that I lost 15k of it.

Comment: @H.Muster No chance, the rep recalc doesn't lie :) (and usually the actually rep shouldn't either; these days anyway)

Comment: @balpha: I was only kidding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was an inconsitency between handling the accept vote, the delete vote, and the corresponding reputation events. The accept vote (hiddenly) sticks around when the answer is deleted, so in the (rare) case that the answer is undeleted, it still counts as accepted. The accept vote is only removed if the OP accepts a different answer, which is what happened here. In other words, the question owner didn't per se unaccept your answer; rather, they accepted another one.

The new all-improved non-sucky realtime reputation updating didn't take this special case into account; it just saw that an accept vote was deleted, and thus deducted 15 reputation, which however had already been deducted at the time the answer was deleted.

The reputation recalc fixed this for your particular case, and Nick has fixed the bug causing this.

Comment: Will the question owner lose their +2 points for accepting at answer deletion time after the fix?  I basically assume that there was the same double deduction bug there.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into this. :)

Comment: @JirkaHanika That's a great point, thanks; we've double-checked that that's fixed as well, and also recalced the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case: If you want to have a first hand complete view into what happenned, visit [this page](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/reputation).  The recalc however wipes all the traces.

Notice also the button at the bottom for self-service restoration (recalc).  The recalc algorithm is less prone to any bugs concerning deleted questions, as it simply ignores them [ex tunc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_tunc).