# Are there any questions for which multiple answers have received enlightened badges?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, enlightened-badge

Since the [*Enlightened* badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/68258#68258) is awarded to [the first undeleted answer that is accepted and has a vote score of 10 or higher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76603/239016), it should be possible for a question to result in multiple Enlightened badges.

For instance, a questions could have two answers, both with a vote score of 10+. If the first is accepted, an Enlightened badge is awarded. Then, for some reason, the answer is unaccepted and deleted, after which the second answer is accepted and an Enlightened badge is awarded for that one.

Has any question on any Stack Exchange site ever resulted in multiple Enlightened badges?

Answer (score 5):

The question [Python Weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474489/4751173) managed to do so:

- [Current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=63011)
- [Previously accepted, now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=45691)

Note that if you don't have 10k on Stack Overflow, the latter will show up as "(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)", so here's a screenshot:

[image]

I found it with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693178) with potential hits - SEDE doesn't know whether an answer has been accepted in the past, nor does it know which post netted a certain user a badge.

Comment: Come to think of it, it _is_ possible to determine if an answer has been accepted in the past. [Here's an example for the one you found](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693189/historically-accepted-answers-for-question-1474489).

Comment: Weirdly enough, acceptance is a vote, while unacceptance doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Ah, right, because a moderator deleted it while it was still accepted.

Comment: [This query yields all questions with multiple accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693190). There are some with four different accepted answers and even one with three once accepted but now deleted answers. Haven't found one with a reaccepted answer, but I'm not sure whether a new acceptance vote overwrites the older one. (Hmm... Hold on...)

Comment: To answer my own question from the previous comment, absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence, but `SELECT PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM Votes
WHERE VoteTypeId = 1
GROUP BY PostId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` yields no results.

Comment: I think the vote for acceptance is still recorded even though the answer is deleted, regardless of who deletes it.

Comment: But only moderators can delete accepted answers :)

Comment: But another answer could be accepted first, after which the erstwhile accepted answer can be deleted. (By its author, in shame?)

Comment: That could very well happen, yes, but that's something that is definitely hard to detect with SEDE (because of the absence of unacceptance votes)

Comment: IIRC "unacceptance" is achieved by deleting the accept vote from the votes table. And that is probably how un-upvote and un-downvote  work as well. Maybe there is a voteshistory table for SE staff ...

Comment: @rene I rather think it generates an entry in the `ReputationHistory` table or something similar.

Comment: Only Adam Lear can tell us ...

Comment: @rene but for these posts (see [my query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693190) I was able to find multiple acceptance votes. So would that mean that when an answer is deleted, it's acceptance vote isn't deleted? That warrants another question.

Comment: To answer my previous comment, [the acceptance vote remains after deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142041/239016), although a new acceptance should remove that vote.

Comment: And I've indeed asked [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385527/239016), about finding unaccepted (or rather de-accepted) answers in the SEDE.

Comment: @SQB I can understand that they won't touch vote history on deleted posts but for sure that leads to anomalies like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301543) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299488)