# How can I find unaccepted answers using the SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer, unaccepted-answer

While researching my question, ["Are there any questions for which multiple answers have received enlightened badges?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385485/239016), I've created [a query that searches for questions with multiple accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693190/questions-with-multiple-accepted-answers). By the looks of it, all these questions have all but one accepted answer deleted, and sometimes all of them.

From what I gather from answers [such as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142041/239016), when an answer is unaccepted (either explicitly or by accepting a different answer), its acceptance vote is deleted (and rep recalculated). This does not happen when that accepted answer is already deleted. That explains why my results show only questions where the previously accepted answers have been deleted.

But is there a way to find *all* answers that were once accepted but were unaccepted later, either explicitly or by accepting another answer?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately SEDE does not contain the additional information required to satisfy this request.

When a post is unaccepted by the asker:

1. its row in `Posts2Votes` is *soft* deleted (`DeletionDate` is changed from `NULL` to `{current date/time}`, but as far as I can tell the `TargetRepChange` and `VoterRepChange` values remain intact).
2. a row is added to `RepHistory` with a `RepHistoryTypeId` of `2` ("Asked (sic) Unaccepts Answer"), whether it changes the answer author's rep or not. This is what's used to recalc.
3. (separate, but related) if a different post is accepted, a new row is added to `Posts2Votes`.

Only votes that have *not been deleted* (`DeletionDate` is still `NULL`) make it to SEDE's `Votes` table, which is a masked subset, as part of the weekly refresh. The SEDE version of Stack Overflow's `Votes` table has ~225MM rows, which - other than a few days of drift - matches the number of rows in production with a `DeletionDate` of `NULL`. The `Posts2Votes` table has an additional ~33MM rows where the `DeletionDate` is present and so these rows are not found in the `Votes` table in SEDE.

Even if those rows were included in the `Votes` table, there is additional information required to piece together whether it was a natural unaccept, or the author (or a moderator) deleted the answer, or the question was deleted (or possibly even migrated?). Which may or may not be useful differentiation for what you would have planned to do with this information. Some of those could be answered by extending the query, but some would require (a) `RepHistory` to be included in SEDE, and/or (b) user information to be unmasked in `Votes`. Both of which are very much the way they are by design.

The only ones you *can* find today are the ones where the *answer* was deleted, not where the accept was removed. The first query in your example (for post ID 90) had an accepted answer of 94, but it was deleted by a moderator, not unaccepted. So the accept vote is still in `Votes`, which is why you can determine that it was accepted once. If the post were still published, any info that would help identify it as a formerly-accepted answer would simply not be accessible to your query.

As an experiment, I flipped the accept away from (and then back to) my own self-answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154742/61305), then looked in the database.

> [image: A little peek inside the sausage factory]

The vote in red will never make it to SEDE, and the vote in orange will disappear in the next refresh (and hence won't appear in [the results of this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1693502/2060859/removed-accepts-by-aaron)). The one in blue (purple?) was the original accept before I accepted my own answer, and hasn't been in SEDE for years (if ever). Right now that query returns `30114577` but after the next refresh it will only return `262596301`.

I just can't prove that to you until next week (and hope a moderator doesn't delete my answer in the meantime). :-)

<sub>(The votes with `RepChange` of `0` are the accept/unaccept of *my own self-answer*.)</sub>

Comment: This was a really heckin cool explanation, thanks for putting this together.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `Posts2Votes` and `RepHistory` are tables, which you use internally at StackExchange but do not release to SEDE?

Comment: @paperskilltrees Yes, there are many internal tables that are either transformed for or suppressed from SEDE, typically for PII reasons.